# ASP MVC List of Users and Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, viewmodel

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET MVC 5 and I'm using Entity Framework. I am using the template project that is provided in visual studio as the start to my own project. I would like to be able to create a ViewModel of Users and Roles where I can see the a list of Users against all the roles they have.

The base project includes the tables `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetUserRoles` which make sense to me. I have usedthe `RoleManager` class provided by `identity` to be able to add a role and then add a user to that role.

```
protected override void Seed(Project.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
    const string roleName = "admin";
    var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
    if (role == null)
    {
        role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
        var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
    }

    var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
    if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name))
    {
        var result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name); // user.Id is retrieved accordingly
    }
}
```

This all works. But now I'm confused on how I can actually view all the users and the roles against them, more specifically how can I bind the data from `AspNetUserRoles` onto a Model and then onto a ViewModel for me to be able to see this and possibly modify? (I'm trying to create an admin panel for managing these users).

I would assume that I can get some control of `AspNetRoles` by possibly extending the [`IdentityRoles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613249(v=vs.108).aspx) class? But there is also an [`IdentityUserRole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613252(v=vs.108).aspx) class?

I'm very confused on how I can approach this problem suggestions and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual solution but I'm sharing this information thinking it might help you in some way or other.I tried creating my own RoleProvider and MembershipProvider for my project. For which I had to implement these abstract classes thatcontained functions for modifying data related to user. 
These are some of the functions in Membership provider....

```
 public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{ UserDb ObjDb;
  UserBs objbs;

public MyMembershipProvider()
    {
        ObjDb = new UserDb();
        objbs = new UserBs();
    }

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordReset
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
 }
```

And these are some functions in RoleProvider

```
 public class MyRoleProvider:RoleProvider
{ UserDb ObjDb;

public MyRoleProvider()
    {
        ObjDb = new UserDb();
    }
    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

Hope this is somewhat near to what you were searching for. All the best.
Here is the function that I think you are talking about which is in the RoleProvider.

```
   public class MyRoleProvider:RoleProvider
   { UserDb ObjDb;
  public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        string[] s = { ObjDb.GetAll().Where(x => x.Username ==username.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault().Privleges };
        return s;
    }
  }
```

Using this function I get the role/Privelege of the user. Then I use it anywhere in the project using IsInRole function which is already there in IPrincipal class.

```
 if (User.IsInRole("SUPERADMIN"))
        {
          //Do something for SUPERADMIN
        }
```

Comment: Does your User class inherit from `IdentityUser`? Because this is where my confusion is coming from. I'm now able to get a list of roles from `IdentityUserRoles` by `db.MyIdentityUser.Roles` but this is returned as a list of ID's and not the `Role` object. I'm wondering how I can try tie the `IdentityRole` to `IdentityUser`, more specifically how I can implement these classes from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`.

Comment: @Toby.....Yes Toby ...there is function called GetRolesForUser in RoleProvider wherein I have written the LINQ query which gets the roles of the user then I use it anywhere in my project using User.IsInRole("ADMIN").....

Answer (score 0):

First in the `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs` register the role manager like this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // register role manager
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>((o, c) => 
        new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(
            new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(c.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())));
    // other codes here
}
```

Then in the action method write this:

```
var users = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().Users;
var roles = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>().Roles;

var usersWithRoles= users.Select(u =>
    new
    {
        UserName = u.UserName,
        Roles = roles.Where(r => u.Roles.Any(ur => ur.RoleId == r.Id)).Select(r => r.Name)
    })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on there in `ConfigureAuth`?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I registered role manager to OWIN's context. So for each request the role manager is generated therefore can be accessed by calling `HttpContext.GetOwinContext()` method.